# How to decrypt in PHP without knowing a key?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I encrypted a text using a key and would like to understand this method if it is vulnerable or not.

Could you tell me if it's easy to decrypt, what methods exist and if maybe I should change the encryption method?

```
$text = "Hello this is my word";
$method = "aes-256-ecb";
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$secretKey= "abcdefghilmnop10032001";

$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($text, $method, $secretKey, $options=0, $iv);
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($encrypted, $method, $secretKey, $options=0, $iv);

print_r($encrypted);
print_r('<br>');    
print_r($decrypted);
```

**The encrypted text is**:

```
Ad4jgTNQlNiSBXGidMoAPZeJkUAxQrYPYKHwc9/80Z0=
```

Besides with `openssl_encrypt` is possible to have a **salt** and so ever a different encrypted text (also if text doesn't change)?

Comment: I'm assuming the question is specifically whether `aes-256-ecb` is considered secure and not a general *is encryption secure* kind of question. I would say this question is probably better suited for [Information security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) however I am willing to bet it's probably already been answered there

Comment: @apokryfos now i never write there. Anyway can you able to say me if at least is possible to have a salt with openssl_encrypt ?

Comment: Salt doesn't make decryption any harder, since you have to store the salt with the encrypted data. The purpose of salt is to make it hard to create a rainbow table.

Comment: Of course you can have a salt. Just use `openssl_encrypt($salt . $text, ...)`.

Comment: I thought it made harder decryption... so aes-256-ecb is safe for you ?

Comment: Salt is used when hashing, not encrypting. It means that different users with the same password will have different hashes, so you can't pre-compute a table with all the hashed passwords.

Comment: @Barmar: Salt is also used when deriving an encryption key from a password, a process which of course involves hashing.

Comment: in the case of encryption the "iv" is something akin to a salt (or using an IV is a type of salting). In that sense `ecb` does not support it. You can of course prepend it yourself but that's just bordering on rolling your own encryption which is something you should never do. Also from what I read you should never use ECB.

Comment: i should never use ECB ? can you suggest other ?

Comment: could go for `cbc`

Comment: @apokryfos now i noticed that with "cbc" output (encrypted data) change every time. Is better no ?

Comment: CBC does support salting so that is why the output is different. This protects from rainbow table attacks. However the real advantage of CBC over ECB is that for ECB each block is always encrypted to the same cyphertext but with CBC the previous block influences the next block so the same block of text will not always be encrypted to the same ciphertext making inference based on data patterns near impossible

Comment: @apokryfos ok now understand...you are great :) last 2 questions: can you tell me if the symbol "&" is forbidden in the decrypted data ? And I have to use encryption to pass a user ID (encrypted) into a URL, in this way I would like to prevent the user from being able to modify the url (id) and access the ids of other users. But in a question on  security.stackexchange which I just opened an user doesn't recommend doing this in my case. What do you think ?

Comment: Typically I think what is done in cases like yours is to use HMAC to provide with a "signature" for the URL and anyone accessing the URL with the correct signature is confirmed to have obtained it legitimately. This being said, I don't think there's any symbols that would be forbidden in the encrypted/decrypted data. However if the id is just a number then this is probably not secure because it's easier to brute-force a ciphertext if you know it's a number. The search space becomes much smaller.

Comment: Actually ignore the part about the id search space. That's completely wrong.

Comment: @apokryfos so in this case is it a wrong approach? do I have to do a hash on the text first and then encrypt the hash with the key?

Comment: If you have e.g. `example.com/users/1` a signed request would look like `example.com/users/1?signature=Q6wNLMHeJXUBRE3d4ZtPjC0nh7Zg4mR6CyJSiw7Yoz8=` then you can be sure that the request is properly signed

Answer (score 1):

You can add salt to the key.

```
$text = "Hello this is my word";
$method = "aes-256-ecb";
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($method);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$secretKey= "abcdefghilmnop10032001";
$salt_length = 10;
$salt = make_salt($salt_length); // You need to define this function

$encrypted = $salt . openssl_encrypt($text, $method, $salt . $secretKey, $options=0, $iv);
$salt = substr($encrypted, 0, $salt_length);
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt(substr($encrypted, $salt_length), $method, $salt . $secretKey, $options=0, $iv);

print_r($encrypted);
print_r('<br>');    
print_r($decrypted);
```

Notice that you have to save the salt along with the encrypted string, so that you can get it back for decrypting.

Comment: and what do you think about "aes-256-ecb" ? Is safe ?

Comment: See [How Safe is AES Encryption](https://www.kryptall.com/index.php/2015-09-24-06-28-54/how-safe-is-safe-is-aes-encryption-safe)

Comment: So is safe and this safety depends by key's lenght. But which difference is there between aes-256-ecb and aes-256-cbc ? And in this case is necessary a salt ?